# Windows Virtual Desktop behind an NVA

Tags: azure

I have a WVD host and I would like to protect it with a NVA (Firewall).

Basically I would like my users to have to connect to our VPN (managed by the NVA) to be able to access the WVD host.

At the moment, using the Remote Desktop Client app, they can access it directly without going through the VPN. It basically connects through the Internet.

How can I make it so the connections are allowed only through the VPN connection (and therefore to the private IP of the WVD host)?

Comment: I guess it is not possible, you can have a better security configuring a MFA, PIM connection, you can for example allow only connection to your AD from a device (machine joined on your AD), region, IP address and many others feature. Try to read more about MFA (multi factory authentication) and PIM (AD Privileged Identity Management).

Comment: @Taguada yes I guess that conditional access and MFA (that we already have activated) could be used in this case. But I was hoping that we could force our users to connect to the VPN for that.

Comment: WVD client uses a public endpoint (https://) and Azure handles all security issue to avoid an attack or any kind of issues like that. But I understand you that could be great a private endpoint like exists to others service like Azure SQL, all of your traffic goes through private network. You can go to https://feedback.azure.com/ and post a feedback about it.

Comment: @Taguada yeah I'm sure that this is going to happen at some point. In the meantime I was thinking that we could maybe run a script on the WVD host and if we detect that users are connected from outside of the VPN we could kick them out. Not sure if we can detect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this is "partially possible"

https://www.sanganakauthority.com/2020/11/can-azure-wvd-inbound-traffic-pass.html

Comment: How does one do it, then? You only posted a link, but that's not really useful since other web sites very often change their content or die entirely. The relevant information should be included directly in the answer, using the link for reference.